# HTML/CSS: IE adding offset to <li> - looks fine in Chrome, FF

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Yes, another IE-only problem for your Thursday. :)

http://jsfiddle.net/dex3703/nwTUm/

This layout looks fine in Chrome, but the li in both the top horizontal menu and the left side vertical menu includes an offset in IE9. IE shows this in the F12 tools when I select an li and look at the "Layout" tab.

(Note that if you look at the fiddle in IE, it displays properly in the result window!)

Any other comments regarding tidying up the markup/css appreciated. Also I'm only interested in IE9.

Comment: It doesn't display properly for me in the jsfiddle window under IE9 but that might be related to the doctype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted the computer and it works fine in IE9 and Chrome.... Hooray web dev.

Comment: Sorry to be answering my own question, I hate that.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the display property to inline for #topnav li will fix it for IE but you will have to do additional work to get it to look right in other browsers.

```
#topnav li 
{
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #767676;
    height: 100%;
    border-top: 4px solid #DBDBDB;
    line-height: 5em; /* for vertical alignment */
    display: inline; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dex3703/nwTUm/

Answer (score 0):

Since it works well in jsfiddle, chances are you aren't using a doctype. Add this to the first line of your page and see if that fixes it: `<!DOCTYPE html>` .  Otherwise you are in quirks mode.

Comment: I have that HTML5 doctype at the top of the HTML page.

Comment: @dex3703 You mean on your site? Is there anything else in front of it?

Comment: If you go to the fiddle you can see the doctype. It's at the very head of the file.

Comment: @dex3703 - Yes. You already said it works there but do you have a doctype on your site where it doesn't work?

Comment: I don't have a site. I"m just looking at the page in the browser locally.

Comment: @dex3703 Still, same question.

Comment: I don't understand your question. The correct doctype is at the head of the file, like I said yesterday in the first comment.

Comment: @dex3703 You said, IE9 adds an offset, which I presumed meant on your site. You said it "works" in jsfiddle . I don't care about jsfiddle. I only care about your site/local copy where you said it doesn't work in IE9. Does your local copy have a doctype?